# Entity Framework - Selection with Include - Observable Colletion

Tags: vba, vb.net, frameworks, entity, loading

I have the following problem:

In my database there are the tables:

Category
Customers
Orders

They are each relationships with 1 - N. Category 1 - N Customers 1 - N Orders

I would like to filter both the Customers table by a category and the Orders table by a time.

Entity Framework offers the Include command for this.

Unfortunately, there is hardly any literature for Visual Basic.

Does anyone know the exact command in Visual Basic?

I would also like to define an Observable Collection that shows me the changes to the Orders table.

Does anyone know a solution??

Thanks Dirk

Ich habe es mit Linq and Join probiert, bekomme aber dann keine Observable Collection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.